# Python equivalent of MATLAB's dataset array

Tags: python, matlab, dataset, machine-learning

I'm trying to convert some code from MATLAB to Python. Is there a Python equivalent to MATLAB's datset array?
http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset-arrays.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to perform numerical operations on the data set, `numpy` would be the way to go.
You can specify arbitrary record types by combining basic numpy `dtypes`, and access the records by their field names, similar to Python's built-in dictionary access.

```
import numpy
myDtype = numpy.dtype([('name', numpy.str_), ('age', numpy.int32), ('score', numpy.float64)])
myData = numpy.empty(10, dtype=myDtype) # Create empty data sets
print myData['age'] # prints all ages
```

You can even save and re-load these data using the `tofile` and 'fromfile` functions in numpy and continue using the named fields:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'wb') as f:
    numpy.ndarray.tofile(myData, f)

with open('myfile.txt', 'rb') as f:
    loadedData = numpy.fromfile(f, dtype=myDtype)
    print loadedData['age']
```

Answer (score 3):

You should look into [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library, which is modeled after R's data frame.

Not to mention this is way better than MATLAB's dataset

Comment: A bit of an overkill for my current needs, but good to know about it. Seems like a very powerful tool

Comment: This is becoming an essential package as part of python scientific computing stack (Numpy, Scipy, Matplotlib, etc..). For example [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) (successor of EPD) includes this in its base edition.

Comment: Took another look at it, I think I'll start using it - seems very useful

Answer (score 1):

A Python [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) can contain keys that are strings or numbers or even other dictionaries like so:

```
>>> d = {"name":"foo", "age":22, "props": {"value":2.1}}
>>> d['props']['value']
2.1
```

I'm assuming this is what you are looking to port over based on this quote from the site you linked to:

> Statistics Toolbox™ has dataset arrays for storing variables with
>   heterogeneous data types. For example, you can combine numeric data,
>   logical data, cell arrays of strings, and categorical arrays in one
>   dataset array variable.

Comment: Is a MATLAB *dataset* a key-value pair data structure? Seems to me a tuple is a closer match than a dictionary.

Comment: [This page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/index-and-search-dataset-arrays.html) shows the use of a dataset that makes me think a dictionary is a better fit, but I don't know MATLAB (only a little Python)

Comment: You're right, it does look like a dictionary. I'm not familiar with this dataset data structure either.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Numpy](https://numpy.org/), it's a third party library mostly used for scientific computing with Python. There's also a page covering [Numpy for Matlab users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935).

I think that you are looking for [Numpy.array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).